# Redux do not update React form inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a user control panel and I have issues binding current data to the input fields.

On page load all inputs are empty, as soon as I update the code, after the hot reload, the inputs are populated correctly...

Basically, in order to populate the form I need to fetch for the current authenticated user, then set the profile data:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {
      getCurrentUser,
      setProfileData,
      setContactsdata,
      setFaresData,
      authenticated,
    } = this.props;

    if (authenticated) {
      getCurrentUser(() => {
        const {
          user,
        } = this.props;

        if (user.profile) setProfileData(user.profile);
        if (user.contacts) setContactsdata(user.contacts);
        if (user.fares) setFaresData(user.fares); 
      });
    }
  }
```

I can not directly bind `user` data because the form has several widget where user can create or update only their profile, contacts, fares, etc... So all of those have their own Redux crud methods.

Everything work as expected, I just need to understand why my data is not visible on page refresh... and yes only after a code reloading...

I can confirm the reducers return the correct data.